# Deriving the joint probability distribution of a transformed rv

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, transformation, density-function, bivariate-distributions

Suppose that A and B are 2 r.v with joint probability distribution given by $f_{AB}(a,b) = -\frac{1}{2}(ln(a)+ln(b))$, if $0 \lt a \lt 1$ and $0 \lt b \lt 1$, and 0 otherwise.

Define $X = A+B$ and $Y = \frac{A}{B}$.

How do I derive the joint distribution of $f_{XY}(x,y)$?

Progress: I know that X will take values $0 \lt x \lt 2$, and the Jacobian = $2y$ .
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jacobian results to me

$$|J|=\frac{x}{(y+1)^2}$$

and after standard calculations the joint density results to me

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{-x}{2(y+1)^2}\log\frac{x^2y}{(y+1)^2}\cdot\left[\mathbb{1}_{(0;1]}(x)\mathbb{1}_{(0;+\infty)}(y)+\mathbb{1}_{(1;2)}(x)\mathbb{1}_{\left(x-1;\frac{1}{x-1}\right)}(y)\right]$$

This because when $x\in(0;1]$ there are no problems but when $1<x<2$, in order to have

$$0<\frac{xy}{y+1}<1$$

And

$$0<\frac{x}{y+1}<1$$

You need to have

$$x-1<y<\frac{1}{x-1}$$

---

**Alternative notation**

---

Joint support can alternatively be expressed by

$$0<x<\min\left(\frac{y+1}{y};y+1\right)$$

$$0<y<+\infty$$

To understand this alternative notation it is enough to do a drawing of support region

[image]

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer, however, I am quite unsure how to read the boundaries for the transformed rv. Do you mind giving it in interval notation? Thanks!

Comment: @I failed math: that is the reason why I added the drawing of joint support. If you understand the drawing you can express it in formulas as you prefer. By the way did you forget to accept my answer?

Comment: Wanted to confirm, can I write the boundaries as $0 \lt x \lt 2$ , unsure about the boundaries for y. Do you mind helping?

Comment: @Ifailedmaths : No, but it is possibile to express joint support in some different ways. See my edits for an useful alternative